# Does the buddy system have the same speed restrictions as egg hatching?

Tags: pokemon-go

Egg hatching requires you to move no faster than a certain speed in order for distance traveled to count towards hatching eggs.

Do the same restrictions apply for moving around with your buddy pokémon?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes.**

It seems that the speed limit is very similar to the one set for hatching eggs - around 10.5 km/h.

Also, the way in which the game calculates distance and speed seems to be exactly the same for both eggs and buddies.

See more information [here](http://www.itechpost.com/articles/29000/20160912/pokemon-go-buddy-system-guide-safe-speed-trainer-faster-ingress.htm).

Comment: @TrentHawkins I've purposefully been going up and down a street near me at around 15 - 20km/h - No progress. There is some at first, but the app quickly catches up and stops counting. it needs to catch you in the act two or three times before it stops counting.

Comment: Aha! [I found the Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4x8vc3/egg_hatching_speed_105_kmh_with_science/) where some experiments were carried out, and explains it in greater detail. If I'm reading it correctly, the game effectively uses a repeating 1min timer and distance traveled to determine speed. So if you start with 30 seconds left on the timer and don't exceed the distance (~175m per 1 minute) you gain full credit for that, but continued driving would put you over the speed detection.

Comment: @TrentHawkins Yep, something like that. Also the path you take matters as the game would take your point A and then some time later it would take your point B and perform some kind of unknown calculation to determine the distance traveled. So you might be on a speeding track doing 1 minute laps with 200km/h+ and you wouldn't be over the limit as far as the app is concerned, so long as A and B is close enough.

Comment: "some kind of unknown calculation" - it's called the pythagorean theorem.